# Need to select a group of text present in xhtml page

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver. I need to select a group of text using Selenium WebDriver. For Selecting the text need to hold the left click of mouse. On releasing of the left click of the mouse one context menu appears. I need to handle the context menu.

Please tell me how  to handle this scenario using Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot do this via selenium.
But you can do it by executing of javascript.

to get selected(highlighted) text

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

to set

```
someElement.setSelectionRange(0, 40);
```

0 -- beginning of selection; 40 -- length to select